# Docker Container npm global affect host or only container?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install, docker-container

When I perform a npm install -g in a Docker container, will it only affect the container or will it actually install the package on the host of the container?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume, for most cases, it will affect only the container, unless you map your npm global directory as a volume from the host to the container at run command, for example:

`docker run [...] -v /usr/lib/node_modules/:/usr/lib/  [...]`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, and I won't be doing that as I just need a couple of packages to serve some static files in the container. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you run inside a docker will affect only the container, that will affect the host **only** if you explicit mount the host dir on the docker.

Doing something like that:
docker run [...] -v /home/youruser/wwwtest:/wwwtest
In this example you will run the npm install on wwwtest of the docker and will affect the local dir /home/youruser/wwwtest.

But like I said, only if you've used this option.